# 0 for arithmetic types, default constructor, otherwise

Tags: c++

Can I say this in C++?

> 0 for arithmetic types, default constructor, otherwise

For example, suppose I'm defining a `vector`-like class, but unlike with `vector`, I want the initial values to be `0`, when the element type is an arithmetic one. How could I do it?

```
template<typename T>
struct my_vector {
    my_vector(size_t size, const T& initial_element = ???
```

I cannot write `0` there, because then this will not work for types that cannot be constructed from `0`.

Comment: Use `const T& initial_element = T();` ?

Comment: In C++11 and later, you have the option of using either `const T& initial_element = T()` or `const T& initial_element = T{}`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `vector` initializes arithmetic types to `0` already

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks! I always thought they were uninitialized, for performance reasons.

Comment: `vector` (and ~all of the standard library actually) always uses value initialization, so primitives always have well defined values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) and has the form of `T()` or `T{}`.  For built in types, you get zero initialization and class types get default initialized.

Answer (score 1):

> How could I do it?

You can do this by having `T()` inplace of `???` as shown below:

```
template<typename T>
struct my_vector {
//----------------------------------------------------vvv------> for default ctor and 0 for arithmetic types types
    my_vector(size_t size, const T& initial_element = T())
   {
   }
};
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zKP8Edce9)

This will use value initialization and work as you require it to.